# Unsuccessful renaming a file in bash

Tags: bash, file-rename, mv

I need to rename a file from "some string[blah].srt" to "some.string.srt";

I use:

```
mv -v "$file" "$newfile.srt"
```

$newfile is $file with dots instead of spaces.

I get the following error:

```
mv: rename dir1/Some string[blah].srt* to dir1/Some.string.srt: No such file or directory
```

Here is the variable values and the dir content:

```
dir content:
total 715368
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Dahan  staff    43K Nov 29  2012 Some string S01E12[blah].srt*
-rw-r--r--  1 Dahan  staff   349M Mar 26 20:42 Some.string.S01E12.avi
newfilename: /Users/Dahan/dir1/Some.string.S01E12.srt
file: /Users/Dahan/dir1/Some string S01E12[blah].srt*
mv: rename /Users/Dahan/dir1/Some string S01E12[blah].srt* to    /Users/Dahan/dir1/Some.string.S01E12.srt: No such file or directory
```

Somehow if I remove the [blah] part from the file it works OK.

Any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: Please show the value of the variables and the contents of the directory.

Comment: It looks like it is interpreting `[blah]` as a character class... Try putting a \ in front of the `[` and the `]`.

Comment: There's also an asterisk. @oridahan, you cannot put wildcard characters inside quotes and expect them to be expanded.

Comment: @glennjackman The filename is only "Some string[blah].srt" without asterisk.

Comment: that's not what your error message says. How do you populate `$file`? I hope you not [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @glennjackman I was (stupidly) parsing ls. Thanks. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Have any idea why it worked when there was no [blah] in the filename?

Comment: I wouldn't say stupid. Take it as a learning opportunity. bash (and the GNU toolset) is a powerful environment but there are lots of gotchas that everyone trips over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem apparently is [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

It worked for the .avi file because it does not have execute permissions, so `ls -F` does not append an asterisk to the filename.